# Rust DRY traits and generics - impl Add and Mul nearly identical

Tags: generics, rust, traits, generic-programming

I have the following toy code which makes use of generics to implement some operations on a 3d vector as a struct of 3 generic elements.

```
use std::ops::Add;
use std::ops::Mul;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Vec3<T> {
    x: T,
    y: T,
    z: T,
}

impl<T> Vec3<T> {
    pub fn new(x: T, y: T, z: T) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 { x, y, z }
    }
}

impl<T: Add<Output = T> + Copy> Add<T> for &Vec3<T> {
    type Output = Vec3<T>;
    fn add(self, other: T) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x + other,
            y: self.y + other,
            z: self.z + other,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Add<Output = T> + Copy> Add<&Vec3<T>> for &Vec3<T> {
    type Output = Vec3<T>;
    fn add(self, other: &Vec3<T>) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x + other.x,
            y: self.y + other.y,
            z: self.z + other.z,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Mul<Output = T> + Copy> Mul<T> for &Vec3<T> {
    type Output = Vec3<T>;
    fn mul(self, other: T) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x * other,
            y: self.y * other,
            z: self.z * other,
        }
    }
}

impl<T: Mul<Output = T> + Copy> Mul<&Vec3<T>> for &Vec3<T> {
    type Output = Vec3<T>;
    fn mul(self, other: &Vec3<T>) -> Vec3<T> {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x * other.x,
            y: self.y * other.y,
            z: self.z * other.z,
        }
    }
}
```

It's pretty plain to see that all I did was copy and paste my `impl Add`'s and replace `Add` for `Mul` and renamed the method names.

This slight repetition brings me to my question - Is there something in rust which generalizes this as well? That is something akin to a generic trait or perhaps "meta trait". In my scenario, a relevant "meta trait" `Op` would have some method `op`. Then, instead of implementing `Add` and `Mul`, one would implement `Op` and `op` would take the place of the `+` and `*` operators respectively.

I explored and found supertraits but I cannot imagine how they could be used as I hope beyond what I imagine would be the basic step:

```
trait Op<T>:Add<T>+Mul<T>{
    fn op(&self)->T;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question for a more general trait for binary operations that will create impls of Add, Mul etc. for you: There is none as far as I'm aware, and I think you cannot [define it yourself](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d08d7a8005329be1719aade7875305d) because of orphan rules. You could:

- Write a [macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/macros.html) for binary ops traits
- Use an existing Vector3, like [nalgebra](https://docs.rs/nalgebra/0.19.0/nalgebra/index.html)'s which implements those traits for you already
- Try to generalize [num_derive](https://docs.rs/num-derive/0.3.0/num_derive/) to work on structs with more than one member

Comment: Great thank you. Macros is a good solution. I'll look into your others. I think this settles this question with macros alone